# How do packages work in Java, specifically when using VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

I'm trying to create a folder called 'a' within a project that I'm currently in in VSCode. Within this folder, I am trying to create a file called Solution.java. When I create this file, I get an error saying "The declared package "" does not match the expected package "a"".

Resolving this issue is easy (just declare package a in Solution.java), but when I go an open the folder 'a' in a different VSCode window, I no longer get the package error in the Solution.java file within folder 'a', meaning I no longer need to declare a package.

Why is this? Why would changing the root project folder in VSCode change the need to declare a package?

[screenshot of package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYfjB.png)

[error going away when switching root folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHiiC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `package` statement like below to the top of the Solution.java.

```
package a;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the identity of A changed.

VS Code recognizes the folder currently opened as project folder:
[image]

When you open A as the project folder, you can definitely create java files under it, and no statement needed;

When you open KICKSTART as the project folder, folder A turns to be a package and if you want to create java files under it, you should follow the java developing rules and add `package a;` on the top line of .java files which under folder a.

More information about package, please refer to [Java-Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the issue you must declare a **package**,

Syntax:

`package package_name.sub_package_name;`

(Declare a subpackage when you've created the file in a folder inside another folder) where the name of the package is the same as the folder in which you've created your java programme file.
[image]